# removing duplicates with aggregated groups in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

Here is a sample of my data:

```
kod <- structure(list(ID_WORKES = c(28029571L, 28029571L, 28029571L, 
28029571L, 28029571L, 28029571L, 28029571L, 28029571L, 28029571L
), TABL_NOM = c(9716L, 9716L, 9716L, 9716L, 9716L, 9716L, 9716L, 
9716L, 9716L), NAME = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "Dim", class = "factor"), ID_SP_NAR = c(20L, 
20L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), KOD_DOR = c(28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L), KOD_DEPO = c(9167L, 9167L, 
9167L, 9167L, 9167L, 9167L, 9167L, 9167L, 9167L), COLUMN_MASH = c(13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), prop_violations = c(0.00561797752808989, 
0.00293255131964809, 0.00495049504950495, 0.00215982721382289, 
0.0120481927710843, 0.00561797752808989, 0.00293255131964809, 
0.00591715976331361, 0.00495049504950495), mash_score = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
W
```

hat I would like to achieve is the following:

for each group formed by the columns `ID_WORKES`, `TABL_NOM`, `NAME`, `KOD_DOR` and `KOD_DEPO`, I would like to have a unique value in `ID_SP_NAR`.

For example here we have six rows where `ID_SP_NAR == 30` with different values for `prop_violations`.
In this case I would like to summarise these six rows such that the remaining value for `prop_violations` equals the mean for these six rows.

The desired output then would look like:

```
  ID_WORKES TABL_NOM NAME KOD_DOR KOD_DEPO ID_SP_NAR prop_violations mash_score
1  28029571     9716  Dim      28     9167        20     0.004500341          0
2  28029571     9716  Dim      28     9167        30     0.005604367          0
```

But there is one more thing: if for some duplicate  values  in prop_violations for ID_SP_NAR, mash_ score has value >0 then left last value for which mash_score has value>0

for example.

```
  ID_WORKES TABL_NOM NAME ID_SP_NAR KOD_DOR KOD_DEPO COLUMN_MASH prop_violations mash_score
1  28029571     9716  Dim        30      28     9167          13          0,0056          0
2  28029571     9716  Dim        30      28     9167          13     0,012048193          0
3  28029571     9716  Dim        30      28     9167          13     0,005617978          0
4  28029571     9716  Dim        30      28     9167          13     0,002932551          1
5  28029571     9716  Dim        30      28     9167          13      0,00591716          0
6  28029571     9716  Dim        30      28     9167          13     0,004950495          0
```

in such case will left only value 0,002932551 by prop_violation for ID_SP_NAR=30,cause mash_score>0
How reach this conditions?

Answer (score 3):

An option using `data.table`:

```
setDT(kod)
kod[, {
        if(any(mash_score)>0) {
            i <- which(mash_score>0)[1L]
            .(prop_violations=prop_violations[i], mash_score=mash_score[i])
        } else 
            .(prop_violations=mean(prop_violations), mash_score=mash_score[1L])
    }, 
    .(ID_WORKES, TABL_NOM, NAME, KOD_DOR, KOD_DEPO, ID_SP_NAR)]
```

output:

```
   ID_WORKES TABL_NOM NAME KOD_DOR KOD_DEPO ID_SP_NAR prop_violations mash_score
1:  28029571     9716  Dim      28     9167        20     0.004500341          0
2:  28029571     9716  Dim      28     9167        30     0.002932551          1
```

data:

```
kod <- structure(list(ID_WORKES = c(28029571L, 28029571L, 28029571L, 
    28029571L, 28029571L, 28029571L, 28029571L, 28029571L, 28029571L
), TABL_NOM = c(9716L, 9716L, 9716L, 9716L, 9716L, 9716L, 9716L, 
    9716L, 9716L), NAME = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L), .Label = "Dim", class = "factor"), ID_SP_NAR = c(20L, 
            20L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), KOD_DOR = c(28L, 28L, 
                28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L), KOD_DEPO = c(9167L, 9167L, 
                    9167L, 9167L, 9167L, 9167L, 9167L, 9167L, 9167L), COLUMN_MASH = c(13L, 
                        13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), prop_violations = c(0.00561797752808989, 
                            0.00293255131964809, 0.00495049504950495, 0.00215982721382289, 
                            0.0120481927710843, 0.00561797752808989, 0.00293255131964809, 
                            0.00591715976331361, 0.00495049504950495), mash_score = c(0L, 
                                0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a solution using the `tidyverse` package:

```
kod %>% 
  group_by(ID_WORKES, TABL_NOM, NAME, KOD_DOR, KOD_DEPO, ID_SP_NAR) %>%
  summarise(prop_violations = if (all(mash_score == 0)) mean(prop_violations) else last(prop_violations[mash_score > 0]))
```

If for a specific group all `mash_score` are equal to zero the average is returned (using `mean`). If at least one `mash_score` is larger than zero then the last value of `prop_violations` for which `mash_score > 0` is returned (using `dplyr::last`).